# getting data from HTTP put

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails, httpwebrequest, put

Note: This question is specific to Grails and jQuery

I'm making an ajax call to my server using PUT:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "admin/services/instance",
    type: "PUT",
    data: {instance: dataAsJSON},
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function(){},
    error: function(){}
});
```

So this call works fine, it calls my controller, but when print params.instance, it's null.

But when i do this as a "POST" it works fine.

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: just return `json_encode($_REQUEST)` from controller to see if you call us going through.

Comment: There wasn't a "$_REQUEST" variable, but there was a "request" variable. but yeah, it seems like the call is going through.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [jQuery manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/): "Note: Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers."

Does your browser support PUT?

Comment: @Neal: I deleted the original, then stumbled upon the right answer. Seemed cleaner at the time to just create a new one.

Comment: @Neal Presumably because this was a new answer, and not a modification of an old answer. Creating a new post for a new answer makes more sense semantically.

Comment: @meagar. not really. but to each their own

Comment: i'm using firefox 4. i assume they do? how do i find out for sure?